# Remove blank regex hits from an array

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, bioinformatics, fasta

I am performing a regex search and wishing to print out only the hits in fasta format (two lines of data: the first beginning with a carrot ">" followed by the hit and the second line without a carrot, but still containing the hit information).
I can successfully generate an output multifasta file, but the carrot and line breaks are included in the output file whether there is a hit or not.

Generated output:

```
    > 

    >

    >TAGCTAGC
    TAGCTAGC
    >

    >GCTAGCTA
    GCTAGCTA
```

Desired output:

```
    >TAGCTAGC
    TAGCTAGC  
    >GCTAGCTA  
    GCTAGCTA
```

Here is my code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl 
    use warnings; 
    use strict; 

    open(CLUSTER, ">", "SequencesToCluster.txt") or die $!; 

    my @TrimmedSequences; 

    my @ArrayofFiles = glob ("~/BLASTdb/Individual_Sequences_*"); 

    foreach my $file (@ArrayofFiles){ 
        open (my $sequence, $file) or die "can't open file: $!"; 
        while (my $line = <$sequence>){ 
            if ($line !~/^>/){ 
            my $seq = $line; 
            $seq =~ s/\R//g; 
            $seq =~ m/([TAGC]{16})(CGGAGCTTTA|GCCATTTCT|TAAAGCTCCG|AGAAATGGGC/; 
            push(@TrimmedSequences, ">", $1, "\n", $1, "\n");  
            } 
       } 
    } 
    #Here I believe I need to manipulate the array to get rid of blank fastas
    print CLUSTER @TrimmedSequences;
```

Comment: You could check that `$1` is defined in your inner while loop, and not push the blank rows on in the first place.

Comment: Your last `$seq =~ ` seems to be missing one `)`

Comment: It is always good to have a second pair of eyes check my typing! Sorry for the typo. Good catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're filtering an array, the tool is `grep`.

E.g.

```
my @new_array = grep { not /^\s*$/ } @old_array;
```

This will filter any element that is just whitespace. In your case, since it's empty *or* just a `>`:

`/^>?\s*$/` instead.

However, that's fixing a problem that need not exist in the first place. You could instead:

```
$seq =~ m/([TAGC]{16})(CGGAGCTTTA|GCCATTTCT|TAAAGCTCCG|AGAAATGGGC)/ 
       && push(@TrimmedSequences, ">", $1, "\n", $1, "\n");
```

And that will only `push` if the regex matches.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @Rob, if the answer helped you solve the problem, please accept the answer. This will help other users with the same issue to quickly find the solution.